# How to merge cells with the GTLRSheets_mergecellsrequest IOS Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-sheets-api

I am trying to utilize the following merge instruction:

```
 func mergecell() {
        let spreadsheetId = "1xAHwkvaYxE5wp7mzHetmZDVO9r1FsLnf6DkVk7mBrdU"

        let request = GTLRSheets_Request.init()

            request.mergeCells = GTLRSheets_MergeCellsRequest.init()

            let test = GTLRSheets_GridRange.init()

            test.startRowIndex = 1
            test.endRowIndex = 11
            test.startColumnIndex = 0
            test.endColumnIndex = 4
            request.mergeCells?.range? = test

           // request.mergeCells?.range?.startRowIndex = 1
          //  request.mergeCells?.range?.endRowIndex = 3
          //  request.mergeCells?.range?.startColumnIndex = 1
         //   request.mergeCells?.range?.endColumnIndex = 3
            request.mergeCells?.mergeType = kGTLRSheets_MergeCellsRequest_MergeType_MergeRows





            let batchUpdate = GTLRSheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.init()
            batchUpdate.requests = [request]

            let createQuery = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsBatchUpdate.query(withObject: batchUpdate, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId)

        service.executeQuery(createQuery) { (ticket, result, NSError) in
```

and it works except that it merges every column together for every individual row as if my "start/endRow/ColumnIndex" values are arbitrary. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

first off what an amazing question (especially granted there is very little information for GoogleSheets-Apis with Swift.) You are really something to take on this endeavour!!!!

The solution is actually quite simple. Just remove the question mark after "range" on the line that sets your merge cell range as shown below:

```
request.mergeCells?.range? = test ->should be-> request.mergeCells?.range = test
```

Good luck with your revolutionary project my man!!!